# How to update Broadcom driver in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, internet

I have been having issues with my broadcom wireless driver, and from what I have seen, most people online say I need to update the driver.

How do I update the driver? Most tutorials use `apt-get` but that does me no good as I am on Arch. What command do I need to run in the terminal to update or reinstall the wireless driver or any driver for that matter?

Comment: What driver are you using? If *you* need to update it, then it is installed from AUR (and you need to rebuild it), otherwise pacman will manage the update with `-Syu`...

Answer (score 0):

Arch linux is using the 'pacman' package manager to install/remove/update... packages or the whole system. 
If you want to install/update a package use the '-S' options (example 'sudo pacman -S emacs'), but you could also upgrade all your installed packages just with 'sudo pacman -Syu'.

Here you got some pacman options [link](http://michael.otacoo.com/manuals/arch-linux/packaging/pacman/), and for further details, look at this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman).

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux.While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: the question was exactly how do i update it. i know how to use pacman, but i have no idea what to do to update the driver